# Disable navigation item

Tags: angularjs

I want to disable my navigation item using this code:

```
md-nav-bar
    md-nav-item A
    md-nav-item(ng-disabled=false) B
```

However, it doesn't work. Looking for the docs but couldn't find anything. How to disable navigation item in correct way?

Comment: Here is the doc:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Of course `ng-disabled` needs to be `true` for the element to be disabled. If you set it to `false`, like you did, nothing will happen....

On top of this, I don't know if you can use that for a nav item. I think its for form elements only. Not sure about this thought.

Comment: oops sorry my mistake, it should be `ng-disabled=true` and still doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

I tried but couldn't find a proper way and didn't have to time to submit a pull/merge request (IF I could fix it that is). I did managed to get a work-around working, which basically intercepts and stops the click from propagating up to be handled by the mb-nav-item:

```html
<md-nav-item md-nav-click="AppCtrl.gotoPage(1)" name="page-1">
  <span ng-click="AppCtrl.gotoPageBlocker(1, $event)">Loan Details</span>
</md-nav-item>
```

Then in you controller/whatever, just define the `gotoPageBlocker()` like so:

```js
function gotoPageBlocker(pageNo, theEvent) {
  if (!userCanAccessPage(pageNo)) {
    theEvent.preventDefault();
    theEvent.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

This will intercept and either block or allow the click event to bubble up to the md-nav-item. Not the best way as using ng-disabled would be SOOO much easier + would have saved me a few hours mucking around, but it works for now. This will screw up the css a bit, so below is my "attempt" at making things look nice in css (well, scss):

```css
.md-nav-item {

  /**
   * We need to move the margin and padding from the parent buttong to the child
   * span. This is so the span intercepts the click from the whole area
   */
  .md-button {
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;

    ._md-nav-button-text span {
      line-height: 24px;
      margin: 0 4px;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      display: block;
      outline: none;
    }
  }

  /**
   * This targets the unselected disabled button
   */
  &[disabled] .md-button._md-nav-button.md-unselected {
    color: #ff0000;
    cursor: inherit;
  }
}
```